# How to build and run Light Table without error?

Tags: linux, lighttable

I've been trying for hours, but can't build and use Light Table. Every time I try to run `deploy/LightTable`, it hangs on a screen that simply says "Light Table". I receive this error*:

`[14381:0519/204037:INFO:CONSOLE(27860)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'thread_STAR_' of undefined", source: file:///home/zaz/Desktop/LightTable/builds/lighttable-0.8.0-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js (27860)`

Here's what I've tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable.git
cd LightTable
bash linux_deps.sh
./deploy/LightTable  # creates frozen window, throws the error above
cd deploy
./LightTable  # creates frozen window, throws the error above
./ltbin  # creates frozen window, throws the error above
```

I also tried similar things after checking out the `atom-shell` branch and the `0.7.2` tag (and cleaning up all the files from the previous build). Each time, I received the error above.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Has Light Table been completely abandoned? It seems the last commit was in March.

---

* Depending on the version I was trying to run, I also received other errors, but I don't think they're relevant (the error above was the only one that appeared for all versions):

```
[18593:0519/222845:INFO:gpu_info_collector_x11.cc(80)] NVCtrl extension does not exist.
[18593:0519/222845:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(226)] Gdk: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large


Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value 11(i) 
[14413:0519/204035:INFO:renderer_main.cc(212)] Renderer process started
```

Comment: For the person who voted to close: The problem I'm having is that Light Table displays the text "Light Table" and does nothing else, instead of functioning as a text editor. It makes for a very dull wallpaper, so I would like it to function as a text editor instead. You can see the exact commands I ran above. You can see the exact error I received above. I've clarified that each one of the commands to run Light Table causes the error, and that I'm using Linux. If something is still not clear, or I haven't been specific enough, please leave a comment.

Comment: Did you try to include the **full** version of bootstrap.js? Also try to include the .css file for bootstrap

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I gave up on LightTable as it seems it is barely maintained any more. I'm using Atom now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A year later (question was written in May 2015, now is June 2016), LightTable 0.8.1 is out, and I tried both Linux binary and cloned it from git, and it works fine.

For complete info, I'm using also Atom, and although I had not problems with "Cannot read property 'something' of undefined"" in Atom core, I met such problems in two or three Atom packages.

Both editors are based on same electron platform, LightTable is beautiful eye candy with quite revolutionary REPL integration, but it **needs** more polish to be usable to same extent as Atom.

For example, LightTable does not have workspace saving by default, that is done via plugin. That's ridiculous.
But although Atom looks so nice and powerful compared to simple editors, with realy huuuge number of available packages/plugins, LightTable is more elegant.
As I don't want to start new semi-religious war Atom vs LightTable resembling vi-vs-emacs, I'll stop here. :)

I can't replicate your problems in LightTable v0.8.1, so I think that answers this question. If not, please add errors you get with v0.8.1.

For info about releases, please check: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/releases

Comment: I'm not interested in LightTable anymore, so I'm not going to test it myself, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks!